# SVNKit : Find all branches of a repository

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

How can I find all the branches in a repository without combing through every revision and check if it has a copy path using SVNKit?
My workplace does not have the habit of creating branches inside branches folder and branches could be created anywhere they see fit.